# Installing Android Image on OrangePi PC 2

Tags: android, sd-card, orange-pi

I downloaded android image from OrangePi official website for OrangePi PC 2.

I burn image to 32 GB SD card via PheonixCard software according to instructions on the OrangePi official website. But I inserted imaged SD card to OrangePi PC 2, android image is not booted.

Firstly, red and green LEDs lighting but then green light is going off and red LED is not turning to green.

I tried everything in my mind and found on internet. Example: using larger SD card, downloading and burning different android images, switching OrangePi adapters but android is not booting.

What can I do anything? I must drive android image on OrangePi PC 2. It is critical for my project.

Could you help me about my problem?

Comment: Why dont you ask on the orange pi forum?

Comment: I don't agree with @greenapps. Already asked to orangepi forum. That doesn't work. I'm waiting for answer too.

Comment: Is there not any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I booted Android 5.1 on Orange Pi PC 2.

Processes that I followed are explained below.

**Step 1:**
Micro SD Card was formatted by SDFormatter application. SD Card format settings that on SDFormatter application are QUICK FORMAT, FORMAT SIZE ADJUSTMENT ON.

**Step 2:**
Android Image was burned on Micro SD Card via PhoenixCard application with Write Mode: Startup setting.

***NOTE: If during the burning Android Image on Micro SD Card error occured, Micro SD Card removed without close the application and then SD Card insterted again and Burn button clicked is clicked. Burning process will finish successfully.***

**Step 3:**
After successfully burning Android Image on SD Card, SD Card removed from computer and inserted to Orange Pi PC 2 board. Powered on the board and waiting process begins. If the image will boot firstly, booting process takes serious time about 4, 5 hour. After 4 - 5 hour, android will become running up.